# How to extend type union props to a react class component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-props, extends

I have two props `showAccountName` and `accountType`.
`accountType` is required only when `showAccountName` is true. When showAccountName is false, accountType is not required.

So, I used a type union -

```
type AccountProps = 
| { showAccountName?: false; accountType: never; }
| { showAccountName?: true; accountType: string; }
```

and trying to extend these props in a class component

```
class UserAccount extends React.PureComponent<AccountProps> 
{ .... }
```

But I am unable to access showAccountName or accountType using `this.props` in UserAccount. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Or is there any other way to make one prop mandatory based on another optional prop? (without using type)
I am new to typescript, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "unable to access"? Do you get a specific error message? When I try your code, it seems to work fine: https://tsplay.dev/NnXxVW

Comment: Why do you make them optional? See [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzL6RN) example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `showAccountName` an optional prop in both cases, only make it optional for the case where it should be falsy (and also just omit the other prop in that case):

```ts
{ showAccountName?: false; }
```

and in the case where you want it to be shown, make both props non-optional:

```ts
{ showAccountName: true; accountType: string; }
```

So, together, it looks like this:

```ts
import {default as React} from 'react';

type AccountProps = 
  | { showAccountName?: false; }
  | { showAccountName: true; accountType: string; };

class UserAccount extends React.PureComponent<AccountProps> {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.showAccountName ? this.props.accountType : 'Account type not shown'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAXzjSghDgHIozKmBuAWACheYAnmBRwAguXIQsAOxgAFemCIBeOLzhwAPojgEAFhADu4yTJgA5DCBQB+AFy0MOAig5wq6rTv1GTU2ZbWDjBQWK5wFKayACpCKA4EIcDSAOZuVNx8POQ4hEQAqi5QfmZwKAAeMCjSSESkFDAAdHJYrADCDJDS1TAAPCWyChBKAHyInqw1KFBwABQAlOM8GhqsMK3Sc54rcL1IwABuI9s7iDB6wASNYIpXPsYS-hZWIjZw55fXt42RT7HCcAcTAG8EEAOkEHg92kTA8y1OvQA9Psjid5pkNHCqEA)